# Dragon Age: Inquisition - The combat sounds are way too loud

Tags: dragon-age-inquisition

The game does not have a separate option for e.g ambient and sfx sounds. This brings a problem when the ambient volume is just right the combat sounds are so loud I have to take off the headphones.

I tried all the dynamic modes and none of them help the issue. Are there any mods or replacement sound packs that fix this?